# I have a polling factory using $timeout but I can't update controller after the $timeout runs.

Tags: angularjs

Please view the factory and the controller below. I want to reference the factory in my controller. I want the controller to have access to a running count from the API.

At the moment, I am unable to update the controller with the new value after the $timeout has run.

Ideally I'd like to keep the $timeout in the factory, and not in the controller. I think the problem is that I don't have a callback in the $timeout, can anyone point me in the right direction?

**The Factory**

```
angular.module('MyPoller', []).factory('MyPoller', function(
  $http,$filter,$timeout) {
  var data = { response: {}, calls: 0 };

  var poller = function (successCallback) {
        $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function (r) {
            data.response = r.data;   
            data.calls++;
            successCallback(data);
            $timeout(poller, 10000);
        });
    };

  return {
        poller: poller
  };
});
```

**The Controller**

```
angular.module('NavBarCtrl', [])
       .controller('NavBarCtrl', function NavBarCtrl($scope, $document, $window, $dropdown, $modal, $timeout, MyPoller) {

    var ctrl = this;

    MyPoller.poller(function(data) {
        ctrl.numberNewMessages = data.calls;
    });
})
```

Comment: What led to the conclusion that you "can't update controller"? Are you trying to display `numberNewMessages` in a template? If so use `$scope.numberNewMessages`.

Comment: I need to retype the message. I will edit and update. I am unable to update the controller with the new value after the $timeout has run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without having to use `$scope.$watch()` by using a factory with a getter. The issue is that `calls` is a primitive and so after reading it the first time Angular will no longer automatically check for changes because it is not expecting a primitive to change. If you instead reference the parent object then Angular will watch for changes automatically. Here's a simplified example to illustrate one way that you might do this:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('dataService', function($timeout) {
    var _data = {
      response: {},
      calls: 0
    };
    var service = {
      get data() {
        return _data;
      }
    };

    function incrementCalls() {
      _data.calls++;
      $timeout(function() {
        incrementCalls();
      }, 2000);
    }

    incrementCalls();
    return service;
  })
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.data = dataService.data;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  Calls: {{data.calls}}
</div>
```

**Update - same as above, but without using a getter**
The bigger issue is that you want to reference the object returned from the service instead of a primitive property on the object. By referencing the object you get the automatic wiring up by Angular to watch for changes.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('dataService', function($timeout) {
    var _data = {
      response: {},
      calls: 0
    };
    var service = {
      data: _data
    };

    function incrementCalls() {
      _data.calls++;
      $timeout(function() {
        incrementCalls();
      }, 2000);
    }

    incrementCalls();
    return service;
  })
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.data = dataService.data;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  Calls: {{data.calls}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Lex.. What would I put in var service = {  get data() {  return _data;  }  };.. is it the $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts') promise?

Comment: and would you say's it a best practice to setup my polling this way, with the $timeout in the factory?

Comment: I can't speak to best practice, but I don't see any issues with putting `$timeout` in the factory since that makes the most sense - especially if you end up using this in multiple controllers. As for what to put in the `get data()` method, it should stay as is. Whatever function you are calling in `$timeout` is where you would put your call to `$http.get()`. When you assign new values to the properties of `_data` Angular will see the change, your controller will see the change, and your view will update appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, Lex. I have one last question. Could this work if the controller is attached to a different module than the factory (see the example modules, although all modules atre part of the same project)?

Comment: never mind. I have a few things to learn. I have accepted your answer, but it would be great if you could point me to a resource on get data() {
        return _data;
      } and why the object has a data property when returned.

Comment: I am trying to understand how we defined "_data" but returned "data"

Comment: You don't have to use a getter and it probably doesn't make a lot of sense when you don't need the corresponding setter. It's just one of many patterns. `get data()` is just a special method that returns the internal `_data` object and can be called without using parentheses. I will update my answer with an alternative that doesn't use a getter and maybe it will make more sense for you.